# docker error in windows container read tcp : wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, windows-container

i am using the latest version of docker for windows. the linux container goes smoothly but i am  getting below problem

> wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

it occurs for fetching some specific image  from repos. In my case i am fetching microsoft/aspnet. i have created a docker file and trying to built my custom image.I have followed the repository instruction for creating a docker file.
the picture is given below

[image]

after this state i am getting this forcibly closed by remote host error.

my dockerfile content is

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7
ARG site_root=.
ADD ${site_root} /inetpub/wwwroot
```

Comment: Please post your dockerfile content. But it looks like a network issue.

Comment: Thanks @jannis for your reply i have added  dockerfile content in post

Comment: What AV (anti-virus) are you using? Try to disabling all AV on your system.

Comment: Just verified as WFM so I guess this is a network issue. Quoting [this](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2318#issuecomment-157553333): "Any unusual networking configuration on your computer? Proxy? VPN? Firewall? Antivirus?"

Comment: I've tried again and again and finally it downloaded what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure exactly why this one worked, as I was trying to do a pull of a couple microsoft images. But in Settings > General > Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS, worked for me. Following that I reverted the change but nice to have that on in the back-pocket. Might be related to firewall settings in Windows. I am using Win 10 Professional.

Comment: Bizarrely, enabling and then disabling this option fixed my problem - or it could be a coincidence, but I'm happy either way :)

Answer (score 3):

I had been consistently encountering this error from inside a corporate network. We added `mcr.microsoft.com` to a firewall white-list, and everything worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

To Debug: 
Check the blocked connections. 
Try unblock internet on the machine, before you whitelist the urls one by one.

Allow the below urls- from windows firewall, any corp proxies, corp firewall

1. "*.docker.io"
2. "*.docker.com"
3. "*.microsoft.com" - windows update dependencies for windows containers
4. "*.mscr.io" -again for microsoft container registries

Worked in my case. Could be more to whitelist, depending on what you are trying to pull.